# delete parent of an element with a class name

Tags: jquery

Why is `.hor` not deleted by clicking on the button?

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.delact').parent('.hor').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='hor'>
  <div class='divname'>lorem</div>
  <div class='inpwrap'>
    <input type='text' class='inpass' data-id=2 value='code323'>
    <div class='btndel delact' data-id=2 title='DELETE'>x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Because `.hor` isn't a parent of `.delact` - it's a grandparent. Use `closest()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method here, not [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

The optional parameter in `.parent()` only filters the **direct** parent:

> ***.parent( [selector ] )***
>   **Returns:** jQuery
>   **Description:** Get the parent of
>   each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally
>   filtered by a selector.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.delact').closest('.hor').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='hor'>
  <div class='divname'>lorem</div>
  <div class='inpwrap'>
    <input type='text' class='inpass' data-id=2 value='code323'>
    <div class='btndel delact' data-id=2 title='DELETE'>x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: what is then the purpose of an argument in parent() function - `https://api.jquery.com/parent/`

Comment: @puerto It only filters the result from `.parent()`. See the documentation linked in the answer.

Comment: of course, and I want to filter parents and select only `.hor` !

Comment: @puerto `.parent()` only selects the **direct** parent. Not all the parents' tree.

Comment: and how it is possible to filter `only direct parent` ?

Comment: ok, your solution works, thanks a lot, but if parent() function selects `only direct parent` can't understand what is the purpose of filtering argument.

Comment: @puerto Imagine your parent is like `<div class="whatevs">`. If you do `.parent('.hey')` on its child, it won't return you anything, since `.hey` doesn't match `.whatevs`.

Comment: Just because it doesn't match your use case doesn't mean that it isn't a valid use case.

Comment: but why would someone write `parent('hey')` if he cannot get anything except direct parent?

Comment: Because you may want to only conditionally select the parent?

Comment: there is no conditionally select here. direct parent is direct parent and just - direct parent.

Comment: @puerto There is no condition in **your** case. You're not the only one using jQuery.

Comment: give me pls an example where `filtering direct parent` works.

Comment: You're asking why you would want to provide the argument in `.parent()`. We provided a use case of why you would use `.parent(argument)`. In your case, you want to use `.closest()` because the element you are trying to select is not a direct parent. It is two different use cases.

Comment: give me pls an example where `filtering direct parent` works.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_parent_class

Answer (score 0):

try with this

`$('.delact').closest('.hor').remove();` use `closest` instead of `parent`

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.delact').closest('.hor').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='hor'>
  <div class='divname'>lorem</div>
  <div class='inpwrap'>
    <input type='text' class='inpass' data-id=2 value='code323'>
    <div class='btndel delact' data-id=2 title='DELETE'>x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```